# Is there a proper way to subclass Tensorflow's Dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was looking at different ways that one can do custom Tensorflow datasets, and I was used to looking at [PyTorch's datasets](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/data_tutorial.html#creating-a-custom-dataset-for-your-files), but when I went to look at [Tensorflow's datasets](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance), I saw this example:

```py
class ArtificialDataset(tf.data.Dataset):
  def _generator(num_samples):
    # Opening the file
    time.sleep(0.03)

    for sample_idx in range(num_samples):
      # Reading data (line, record) from the file
      time.sleep(0.015)

      yield (sample_idx,)

  def __new__(cls, num_samples=3):
    return tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        cls._generator,
        output_signature = tf.TensorSpec(shape = (1,), dtype = tf.int64),
        args=(num_samples,)
        )
```

But two questions came up:

1. This looks like all it does is that when the object is instantiated, the `__new__` method just calls the `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator` static method. So why not just call it? Why is there a point of even subclassing `tf.data.Dataset`? Are there any methods that are even used from `tf.data.Dataset`?
2. Would there be a way to do it like a data generator, where one fills out an `__iter__` method while inheriting from `tf.data.Dataset`? Idk, something like

```py
class MyDataLoader(tf.data.Dataset):
  def __init__(self, path, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.data = pd.read_csv(path)

  def __iter__(self):
    for datum in self.data.iterrows():
      yield datum
```

Thank you all very much!

Comment: Great question!  And the TF documentation is lacking, so definitely up-voted.

Answer (score 2):

### Question 1

That example is just encapsulating a dataset with a generator in a class. It is inheriting from `tf.data.Dataset` because [`from_generator()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator) returns a `tf.data.Dataset` -based object. However, no methods of `tf.data.Dataset` are used as seen in the example. Thus, answer to question 1: yes, it can be called straight without using the class.

### Question 2

Yes. It can be done like that.

Another, similar way would be to use [`tf.keras.utils.Sequence`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Sequence) like [here](https://medium.com/@mrgarg.rajat/training-on-large-datasets-that-dont-fit-in-memory-in-keras-60a974785d71).

Comment: Up-voted for suggestion to go the `tf.keras.utils.Sequence` route.  Just like PyTorch, inherit from an existing class then define `__init__`, `__len__`, and `__getitem__`